# Spanner - Entity Framework System.InvalidOperationException: 'No primary key was found in the database for table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to code first a database with spanner and Entity Framework Core.

But when `EnsureCreated` is hit, the application throws the following exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No primary key was found in the database for table Table DistributionChannel. Call SpannerModelValidationConnectionProvider.Instance.EnableDatabaseModelValidation(false) to disable model validation if this error is a false positive.'

[image: Exception]

DistributionChannel:

```cs
public class DistributionChannel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`SpannerContext`:

```cs
public class SpannerContext : DbContext, IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<SpannerContext>
{
    public SpannerContext()
    {
    }

    public SpannerContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<DistributionChannel> DistributionChannels { get; set; }

    public SpannerContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SpannerContext>();

        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath($"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}/Configurations")
            .AddJsonFile("migrations.json")
            .Build();

        var configuration = configBuilder.GetSpannerConfiguration();

        var databaseName = DatabaseName.FromProjectInstanceDatabase(configuration.ProjectId, configuration.InstanceId, configuration.DatabaseId);
        var dataSource = $"Data Source={databaseName}";

        var connectionString = new SpannerConnectionStringBuilder(dataSource).ConnectionString;

        builder.UseSpanner(connectionString,
            config => { config.CommandTimeout(configuration.Timeout); });

        return new SpannerContext(builder.Options);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DistributionChannelConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.AddJsonFields();

    }
}
```

`DistributionChannelConfiguration`:

```cs
internal class DistributionChannelConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DistributionChannel>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DistributionChannel> entity)
    {
        entity.ToTable("DistributionChannel");
        
        entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        entity.Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

**Startup**

I'm calling the `Database.EnsureCreated` method:

```cs
//rest of code 

using var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SpannerContext>();
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the Entity Framework provider. It will be fixed here: https://github.com/googleapis/dotnet-spanner-entity-framework/pull/287

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment, for now I'll use the migrations only and create the database first